# In java why always child class call the super class constructor ? I want to the internal flow

Tags: java, constructor

I know how these stuff flow but I want to know when we make the object of child class it calls the parent class no arg constructor first. But i want to know the internal thing.

Comment: Which part of the official tutorial is unclear to you? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html

Comment: To ensure that the "parent part" of the object is in a proper state after construction finished.

Comment: Because if you have a SupersonicPlane extending a Plane, and SupersonicPlane's constructor didn't call the Plane constructor, then the wheels, wings, cockpit etc. that are initialized in the Plane constructor wouldn't be initialized anymore. A SupersonicPlane without wheels and wings wouldn't be very usable, would it?

Answer (score 4):

The parent class constructor needs to be called before the subclass constructor. This will ensure that if you call any methods on the parent class in your constructor, the parent class has already been set up correctly.

Answer (score 0):

The first magic is, if a class has no written constructor, a default no-args constructor is generated in the .class file.

In a constructor there is always a call to a super constructor as first statement. If there is no super call, magically a `super()` (no-args) is generated in the .class file. However you may also explicitly call any super constructor.

Then also you can instead call another constructor with `this( ... )`.

Also magically generated then in the constructor are all field initializations of the form `type fieldName = expression` (with an assignment). And last follows the remaining written constructor code.

Before construction fields have the default value (`null 0 0.0 false`).

This ensures that you have a fully initialized parent object to begin with.

Though this depends on the (super) constructor not throwing an exception and not calling overridable methods. (An overriden method in the child class would have unitialized child fields, overwritten coming back from the super constructor by the child constructors field initialization.)

Sorry, this is amazingly complex. You could experiment a bit. Basic usage is simple.